# Limit of a multivariable function with log.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the limit of

$$f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\log|x+y|$$

as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

I tried using Squeeze Theorem but couldn't think of an upper bound for it. I know the limit of $t log(t)$ is 0 as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit **does not exist**. Indeed, $f(x,x)=x^2\log (4x^2)$ tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$ (using $t=4x^2$ in what you wrote), whereas $f(x,-x)=2x^2\log 0=-\infty$ for all $x$ (and in particular as $x\to 0$).

Comment: This reason is not valid, because $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: (x, -x) \notin (\operatorname{dom}(f))'$.

Comment: @Botond the domain was left unspecified, in which case it is perfectly valid to interpret (as I did) the domain to be $\mathbb R^2$ and the range $\mathbb R\cup \{-\infty\}$. However, even with your domain my argument goes through: take any fixed $x$ and consider $f(x+\epsilon, -x)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$: you will see that it tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, it's not $(\operatorname{dom}(f))'$, just $\operatorname{dom}(f)$; but I can't edit that comment anymore.

Comment: @Botond I figured that it was you meant, but in any case - do you see why the objection you raised is not relevant to this particular problem?

Comment: But the expression is not meaningful at the points of the form $(x, -x)$. And $-\infty$ is not a number. So it's not valid. Yes, we can see that $f\forall x, (x+\varepsilon, -x) \to -\infty$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. So? It does mean only that it diverges on the points of the form $(x, -x)$.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line, it is very common in most real analysis textbooks to consider functions taking values in the extended reals, this is a good opportunity for you to learn about this subject - but don't let your ignorance result in an unnecessary downvote!

Comment: Per your question of "so?", it means that we can easily construct a sequence lying in your restricted domain on which the function limit (in your restricted domain) converges to $-\infty$ using standard analysis arguments. Choose a sequence $x_n$ tending to $0$ and $\epsilon_n$ sufficiently small such that $f(x_n+\epsilon_n,-x_n)<-n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n+\epsilon_n,-x_n)=-\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97044/discussion-between-pre-kidney-and-botond).

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the chat in time because of I was thinking about your sequential  argument, because it seems to be right, but wolfram alpha also thinks that the limit is zero, and I don't see why: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x%5E2%2By%5E2)log(%7Cx%2By%7C)+as+(x,y)+to+(0,0)

Comment: I can't change my vote to upvote unless you edit your answer, so, please do a minor edit in your answer.

Comment: @Botond I have put my answer in bold face

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not Equate x to y since they approach the same value?

https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/limit-calculator/?f=2x%5E2*log%282x%29&var=x&val=0&dir=&steps=on